# AJAX not working here and some questions?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

After much research, I have found that Laravel is very nice. I have a homepage opening with an animation and after it the menu and page content splits into each side. With the links clicked, I only want content to change. I tried jQuery/ajax to work with. But I have a question, I want the links inside the content and sidebar-menu to change content. Can you show me the way to do that?

This is my ajax.js :

```
 $(document).ready( function() {

    $("#content ul li a").click( function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         $('#page').load(this.href);
         return false;
    });

});
```

This is my Articles controller:

```
<?php
class Articles_Controller extends Base_Controller
{

    public $restful = true;
    public $layout = 'layouts.default';

    public function get_index(){
        $this->layout->title = "Anasayfa";
        $this->layout->content = View::make('articles.index')
             ->with('articles',Article::order_by('id')->get());
    }

    public function get_view($id){
        $this->layout->title = "Hizmetlerimiz";
        $this->layout->content = View::make('articles.view')
             ->with('article',Article::find($id));
    }
}
```

My `default.blade.php`:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="page">
        {{ $content }}
    </div>

    <div id="sidebar">
        <div id="sidebar-content">
        <!-- MENU -->
        <ul id="menu">
            <li class="current"><a href="#">ANASAYFA</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">HAKKIMIZDA</a></li>
// ...
```

My `index.blade.php`:

```
<div id="content">

    @foreach($articles as $article)
    <ul class="blog-medium">
        <li>    
            <div class="blog-medium-text">
                <h1><a href="./post.html">{{$article-> title }} </a></h1>
                <p class="blog-medium-excerpt"><p>Tek kişilik sınıflarda YGS - LYS hazırlık programımızda dersler özel&#8230;<br />
                {{ HTML::link_to_route('article','devamı', array($article->id)) }}</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

My `view.blade.php`:

```
<div id="content">
    <h1>{{$article->title}}</h1>
    <p>{{$article->content}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: your foreach loop is incorrect. is it modified here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in your Jquery

```
$(function() 
{
    $("#content ul li a").click( function()
    {
        var url = $(this).attr('href'); // Get href value from <a>

        $('#page').load(url);

        return false; // No need for e.preventDefault() if return false;
    });
});
```

This should work assuming that the href value is the full or relative path to the controllers method.

As you are using restful controllers, consider that AJAX is capable of GET and POST HTTP methods. You can segregate all POST and GET data into seperate functions and also check if the request is Ajax in Laravel using:

```
if (Request::ajax())
{
    ... // The request is AJAX, do ajax stuff

    return Response::json(array('action' => 'complete'));
}
```